# If a variable is undefined set new variable to a defined one, without 'if' statement?

Tags: javascript

I know an if statement can easily accomplish this. I'm just wondering if there's anything that could be done even more simply.

For example:

```
var a
var b='this has a value'
var c = don't use a, instead use b
```

Comment: What exactly has to be true about `a` for you to not want to "use" it?

Comment: It was the simplest way to ask my question. It looks like @CertainPerformance has given me what I need. For more detail, I'm instantiating an IndexedDB database that may never have data in it, or not until later. When I load my page, I want it to check if there's data and populate an element with that data. If not, set the values temporarily until there is data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a`, if defined, will be truthy, just alternate:

```
var c = a || b;
```

```js
let a1;
let b1 = 5;
let c1 = a1 || b1;
console.log(c1);


let a2 = 'truthy';
let b2 = 10;
let c2 = a2 || b2;
console.log(c2);
```

Otherwise, if `a` can be defined but falsey, use the conditional operator:

```
var c = a !== undefined ? a : b;
```

```js
let a1 = null;
let b1 = 5;
let c1 = a1 !== undefined ? a1 : b1;
console.log(c1);
```

Comment: in addition: let c = (typeof a === 'undefined') ? b : a;

Comment: Sure, if you're actually worried about there being an outer variable name called `undefined`, or about the global `undefined` property having been overwritten (in very ancient environments, pre-ES5), but those are *very strange* edge cases